# Using java streams to find if a number is prime or not

Tags: java, java-stream, primes

I am reading *Cracking the Coding Interview* and it has an example of finding prime number which I ran on JShell

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
  for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

then I am trying to convert this to streams in java, but finding this difficult as mentioned

```
boolean isPrimeStream(int n) {
  return IntStream.range(0, n) // how to do similar to for loop above
    .anyMatch(i -> n % i == 0);  // i think this is the reason for failure
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`IntStream.noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#noneMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) there as:

```
boolean isPrimeStream(int n) {
    return IntStream.range(2, n) // note  division by zero possible in your attempt
                    .noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
}
```

***Edit***: As pointed in comments by Andreas, using `range(2, n)` to avoid division by zero and since division by 1 would always lead to the condition being true and returning the result as `false` otherwise.

> Returns whether ***no elements*** of this stream match the provided
>   predicate

Your current code is using [`IntStream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate))

> Returns whether ***any elements*** of this stream match the provided
>   predicate

which is why it would return `true` if the condition specified is satisfied for any input instead of when the method is supposed to return `false`.

---

> how to do similar to for loop above

With [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) or above you could use [`IntStrem.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate(int,java.util.function.IntPredicate,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) as

```
private boolean isPrimeStream(int n) {
    return IntStream.iterate(2, i -> i * i <= n, i -> i + 1) // similar to the loop
                    .noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem one, you should be using `noneMatch` (not `anyMatch`). Problem two, your range is off. Use `rangeClosed` (or add one to your end) which should be the square root of `n` (not just `n`) - and you started with 2 as an initial value in your first test. Also, you might as well make the method `static`. Like,

```
static boolean isPrimeStream(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(n)) 
            .noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
}
```

Also, we can improve your first example by handling `2` as a special case. That allows you to begin with three and increment by two skipping all even values.

```
static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (n == 1 || n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the point of using Java8 streams to get this thing done. To me you are reinventing the wheel. This one liner will be suffice.

```
BigInteger.valueOf(n).isProbablePrime(50);
```

Also notice that there are some problems which can be better solved using streams. But that does not mean stream is the silver bullet to solve all your problems.

Here's an excerpt from the Documentation about certainty.

> For a large known prime, and for any certainty > 0, is it accurate to
>   say that b.isProbablePrime(certainty) will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Java8Practice;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PrintPrimeNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    List<Integer> primes = list.stream().filter(n -> isPrime(n)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(primes);
}

static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    return IntStream.range(2, n).noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
 }
}

/*Output 
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
*/
```