# IntStream instead of for loop without condition

Tags: java, java-stream

In answer to my question user nullpointer suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905940/10824969 how for loops can be converted to stream way using `IntStream.iterate`.

I had a similar for loop condition with which I iterate

```
void printMultiples(int number, int threshold) {
    for (int i = number; ; i = i + threshold) {
        if (i < threshold) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

trying to convert this to

```
IntStream.iterate(number, i -> i + number).forEach(System.out::println);
                                              ^^
// Non-short-circuit operation consumes the infinite stream
```

there is a warning with IDE in above code. I also tried to check for multiples using `IntStream.range`, the below prints all the numbers instead

```
IntStream.range(number, threshold).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What do you expect for your code?

Answer (score 5):

You can `filter` your stream as

```
IntStream.range(number, threshold)
    .filter(i -> i % number == 0) // only those divisible by number
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Or if Java-9 or above is an option, you can possibly use

```
IntStream.iterate(number, i -> i < threshold, i -> i + number)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or more appropriately as it sounds like a while loop, use [`Intstream.takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) as :

```
IntStream.iterate(number, i -> i + number)
        .takeWhile(i -> i < threshold)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```