# use a method to read numbers from a text file and return the prime numbers

Tags: java

the question says: Create a class named HW09. In this class implement a method named primeCounter
with the following signature, that takes a file name as string (for example “numbers.txt”) and returns the number of prime numbers in the text file. Assume the text file only contains integer numbers.

I tried to build the code for the program But I keep getting these error messages and I'm not sure how to fix them and get the program running again. My knowledge of the file access concept is very weak and my professor is horrible. I hope someone can help me understand what went wrong

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

 class HW09 {
        
    public static int primeCounter(String fileName) throws IOException {
        int count= 0;
        int number;
        String x= null;
        File filename= new File("C:/Users/black/Desktop/file.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(filename);
        BufferedReader data= null;
        data= new BufferedReader (new FileReader(filename));
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            number= Integer.parseInt(x);
            int see=0;
            for (int i =1; i<=number; i++) {
                if (number%i==0) {
                    see = see+1;
                }
                if (see>2) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (see==2) {
                count = count+1;
            }
            
        }
        return count;
        
    }
    public static void main (String args []) {
        try {
        String file= ("C:/Users/black/Desktop/file.txt");
        System.out.println(HW09.primeCounter(file));
    }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find file! ");
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages?

Comment: 1) When declaring your File, refer to the string you're passing into the method rather than retyping it; this will ensure consistency if the file path changes.  2)  Your BufferedReader data never actually gets used.  3) I like that you are not doing everything in main(), but it will help to break things out even more.  Have separate methods for: getting the file data; iterating through all the numbers in the data; checking a single number to see if it is prime (return true or false).

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of issues with your current code, first and foremost is the lack of separation of concerns. I would start with a simple method to determine if a single number is prime. I wrote such a method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905978/2970947), and that looks like

```
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (n == 1 || n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you want to read numbers with your `Scanner`. And check if they are prime. And don't forget to close the `Scanner` when you're done. Using a `try-with-resources` takes care of that. Like,

```
public static int primeCounter(String fileName) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            int v = s.nextInt();
            if (isPrime(v)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Finally, when constructing a path, it's better to use the system properties to get the home folder. That way, it can work on other people's machines more easily,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        String file = new File(
                System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop/file.txt").getPath();
        System.out.println(primeCounter(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find file! ");
    }
}
```

And I created a file to test against,

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/file.txt
13
11
7
5
3
2
4
```

After running the program I get, as expected,

```
6
```

Comment: The `isPrime` method does not handle `1` correctly.

Comment: @iota Thanks. Always appreciate constructive criticism.